# How to properly run a Rails app inside Electron?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, electron

I am very new to Electron, just tried to follow the Documentation.
I was able to run a html in Electron and it worked fine.

Then I tried to load a Rails app with BrowserWindow loadUrl, but the javascripts of the app are not working inside Electron.

My main is this index.js here:

```
var app = require ('app')
var BrowserWindow = require ('browser-window')
app.on('ready', function(){
    var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width:1115,
        height:945
    })
    mainWindow.loadUrl('http://my-app-at-heroku.herokuapp.com')
})
```

Running the server in my machine and loading http://localhost:3000 has the same behavior.  The app appears, but the js don't work.

What have I missed?  How do I properly run a Rails app inside Electron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, the correct way to solve this is to set the `"node-integration"` option on BrowserWindow to `false`, like so:

```
var app = require ('app')
var BrowserWindow = require ('browser-window')
app.on('ready', function(){
    var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width:1115,
        height:945,
        "node-integration": false
    })
    mainWindow.loadUrl('http://my-app-at-heroku.herokuapp.com')
})
```

Source: https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/254#issuecomment-82322963

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution.

In my Rails app, I had to include the following in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.module = undefined;
  window.require = undefined;
</script>
```