# Can I build an electron app from rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, electron, desktop-application

I am working on a Rails project and I am trying to figure out if I can use Electron to create a desktop app or if there is another way to turn a Rails app into a desktop app.

Comment: By the looks of it you can open a browser instance inside an electron app and load the rails app. Read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967854/how-to-properly-run-a-rails-app-inside-electron